# android gradle duplicate jar

Tags: android, gradle, duplicates, proguard

I use `gradle` to build my project.

my project `:wxy`

my lib-project `:news`

in `:wxy build.gradle`

```
android{    
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':news')
}
```

in `:news build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    provided files('libs/Android_Location_V1.2.0.jar')
}
```

`:wxy` and `:news` have the same jar "Android_Location_V1.2.0.jar" with same SHA hash. It builds successfully in `:wxy:assembleDebug`.

However, build failed in `:wxy:assembleRelease` which open proguard. It has error message:

```
Execution failed for task ':wxy:proguardRelease'.
java.io.IOException: Can't write
[C:\src\wxy\wxy\wxy\build\intermediates\classes-proguard\release\classes.jar] 
(Can't read [C:\src\wxy\wxy\wxy\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\wxy\360news\unspecified\libs\Android_Location_V1.2.0.jar(;;;;;;!META-INF/MANIFEST.MF)] 
(Duplicate zip entry [com/a/bn.class == Android_Location_V1.2.0.jar:com/aps/u.class]))
```

It seems that I compile the `Location.jar` twice. The 'provided' has no effect.

How should I do?

**EDIT**
wxy/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "*****"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 55555
        versionName "4.1.3"
        testApplicationId '******'
    }



    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
    }

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

    productFlavors {
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']  
        }
    }

    signingConfigs {
        key {
            storeFile file("*****");
            storePassword "****"
            keyAlias "****"
            keyPassword "***"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.cfg'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.key
        }

        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
     compile project(':news')
     compile project(':libs:alipay')
    androidTestCompile 'org.easymock:easymock:3.3.1'

}
```

news/build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

def propGroup = '*****'
def propArtifactId = '****'
def propVersion = '1.0.0'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.2'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']  
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF'
        exclude 'libs/Android_Location_V1.2.0.jar'
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/sharenews.jar')
    provided files('libs/Android_Location_V1.2.0.jar')
    provided files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories.mavenDeployer {
        repository(url:    '*****') {
        authentication(userName: "deployment", password: "deployment123")
        pom.groupId = propGroup
        pom.version = propVersion
        pom.artifactId = propArtifactId
        pom.name = propArtifactId
        pom.packaging = 'aar'
    }
}
}
```

my proguard.cfg

```
-optimizationpasses 5
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
#-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify
-verbose
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

-dontwarn org.jboss.netty.**
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-keep public class * extends android.app.Activity
-keep public class * extends android.app.Application
-keep public class * extends android.app.Service
-keep public class * extends android.content.BroadcastReceiver
-keep public class * extends android.content.ContentProvider
-keep public class * extends android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper
-keep public class * extends android.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends android.view.View
-keep class * extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment
-keep public class com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

-keep class **.R$* {*;}
-keep class com.unionpay.upomp.bypay.** {*;}
-keep class android.support.v4.** {*;}
-dontwarn android.support.v4.**      
-keep public class * implements java.io.Serializable {  
            public *;  
}  
-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {  
        static final long serialVersionUID;  
        private static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[]            serialPersistentFields;  
        private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);  
        private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream); 
        java.lang.Object writeReplace();  
        java.lang.Object readResolve();  
}  


-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements         com.comisys.gudong.client.task.pay.PayTask{
    public <init>(android.app.Activity);
}

-keepclassmembers class com.comisys.gudong.client.model.**{
    public void set*(***);
    public *** get*();
    public boolean is*();
    <fields>;
}
-keepclassmembers class com.comisys.gudong.client.net.model.**{
    public void set*(***);
    public *** get*();
    public boolean is*();
    <fields>;
}
-keepclassmembers class com.comisys.gudong.client.uiintepret.bean.**{
    public void set*(***);
    public *** get*();
    public boolean is*();
    <fields>;
}

-keep interface com.comisys.gudong.client.net.model.protocal.IUserEncode{
    *;
}
-keepclassmembers class * implements     com.comisys.gudong.client.net.model.protocal.IUserEncode {
    <fields>;
    public void set*(***);
    public *** get*();
    public boolean is*();
}

-keep interface     com.comisys.gudong.client.net.model.protocal.IUserEncode$IENCODE{
    *;
}
-keep class * implements     com.comisys.gudong.client.net.model.protocal.IUserEncode$IENCODE{
    public ** encode(**);
    public ** decode(**);
}

-keepclassmembers enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
-keepclassmembers class * extends android.app.Activity{
    public void permissionFilter(android.view.View);
}




#第三方包
-keep public class com.comisys.pinyin.Helper
{
    public *;
}

-keep class org.jboss.** {*;}
-keep class com.iflytek.** {*;}
-keep class com.mapabc.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.mapabc.**   
-keep class cn.yunzhisheng.** {*;}
-keep class com.comisys.gudong.client.util.pinyin.**{*;}

#-libraryjars ../business/libs/fastjson-1.1.37.jar
-keep class com.alibaba.fastjson.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.alibaba.fastjson.**

#-libraryjars /libs/Android_Location_V1.2.0.jar
#-libraryjars /libs/Android_Services_V2.2.0.jar
#-libraryjars /libs/Android_Map_V2.2.0.jar
-keep class com.amap.api.**{*;}
-dontwarn com.amap.**
-dontwarn demo.**
-dontwarn com.so.newsplugin.**
-keep class ru.truba.touchgallery.**{*;}
-dontwarn ru.truba.touchgallery.**
-keepattributes Signature
-keep class com.comisys.gudong.client.ui.view.MyGallery{
    *;
}
# begin 360news
#反射类不能进行混淆编译，需加入
-dontwarn com.so.newsplugin.model.**
-keep class com.so.newsplugin.model.** {*;}

-dontwarn com.so.newsplugin.service.**
-keep class com.so.newsplugin.service.** {*;}

-dontwarn com.so.newsplugin.activity.**
-keep class com.so.newsplugin.activity.** {*;}

-dontwarn com.so.newsplugin.fragment.**
-keep class com.so.newsplugin.fragment.** {*;}

-dontwarn com.so.newsplugin.widget.**
-keep class com.so.newsplugin.widget.** {*;}

-dontwarn com.so.newsplugin.imgcache.**
-keep class com.so.newsplugin.imgcache.** {*;}

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
   public *;
}

# end 360news

-keep class com.comisys.gudong.client.WebViewActivity$HtmlJSInterface{
    *;
}
```

only the

```
-keep class com.amap.api.**{*;}

-dontwarn com.amap.**
```

affact the Location.jar.I keep all classes in Location.jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah,I make it.

The solution is at [Computing Version code in multi-flavor setup](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/tips#TOC-Computing-Version-code-in-multi-flavor-setup.).
Capture **Handling transitive dependencies for local artifacts (jars and aar)**.

solution 1,upload the jar to maven repository.And reference it.

```
dependencies {
    compile '*****'
}
```

solution 2, create a libproject,move the jar into the project.
 :wxy and :news both reference it.

```
dependencies {
    compile project('*****')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you put these

```
    buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
            }
        }
    }
```

or

```
 buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                     proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: without proguard. It works ok. However It failed with proguard.

Comment: Can you please post your full code of build.gradle file.

Comment: are you suggesting to disable proguard to fix the problem?

Comment: @ZebulonLi  I don't think disabling proguard  is a good solution.May be it's a temporary solution.What I am thinking is that there can be some problem with 'proguard.cfg' file .I have edited my answer see if it can help.

Comment: @Soham   Sorry,I copy the code forget to change the proguard switch. I changed it.I will add my proguard.cfg